# How do I make sure the instruction inside an if statement, which is also inside a for loop, gets executed only once?

Tags: java

Let's say I have this:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < pointsArray.size(); i++) {
     ...
     some setup stuff
     ...
     if(pointOnMinimap()) {
         click(pointsArray.get(i);
     }
 }
```

Whenever it runs, it clicks the point on the minimap multiple times, until the next one from the pointsArray appears. How do I make sure click() runs a single time, for each point?

**EDIT 1** As GhostCat mentioned, I added the click function, maybe this could be the problem.

```java
public void click(int x, int y) {
    game.getCanvas().dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(game.getCanvas(),
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            0,
            x, y,
            0,
            false));
    game.getCanvas().dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(game.getCanvas(),
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            0,
            x, y,
            0,
            false));
    game.getCanvas().dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(game.getCanvas(),
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            0,
            x, y,
            0,
            false));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a boolean to check if it's been clicked? Also, why do you have that if inside a loop? Shouldn't that be in some event-driven function? And, I suposse that you have missed one `)` on `click(pointsArray.get(i);`

Comment: Try adding a `break` statement after the `click` method.

Comment: You mean once, or once per iteration? Unless there is another loop in there, this should execute exactly once per iteration.

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but I don't get your point. The code you are showing will click each point either 0 or 1 time. So please **include** the part of your code that causes multiple clicks! In that sense: please read [mcve]!

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, one per iteration. There's no other loop.

Comment: @Arpit Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Does your loop run inside any event handler?

Comment: @Shirkam I tried Bathsheba's  answer below. Still not working. And no, it's not event-driven. It checks if the player's location is smaller than n and returns true.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ActionListener on a JButton.

Comment: Aha. So you may have an infinity of events going on - the events you dispatch cause your event listener to be activated again. Please rewrite your program into a [mcve], otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: Is your `click` method called anywhere else, such as in response to mouse events?  If so, you've got yourself into an endless loop, since it's `click` that's creating those mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

Something on the lines of

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < pointsArray.size(); i++) {    
    if (j == 0 && pointOnMinimap()){
         j = 1;
         click(pointsArray.get(i);
     }
```

will do it. This is idiomatic elegant C but alas in Java it's really an abuse of an `int` type. Quiche eaters and girls might want `j` defined as a `boolean` type but then you'd need extra scoping blocks over the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some condition which when true would lead you to call the `pointsOnMiniMap` function

```
for(int i = 0; i < pointsArray.size(); i++) {
     ...
     some setup stuff
     ...
     if(SOME_CONDITION && pointOnMinimap()) {
         click(pointsArray.get(i);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I do have a function which checks if the point is visible on the minimap or not. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide with some sample data. I think `click(pointsArray.get(i);` would be called every time you condition  `if(pointOnMinimap())` return true;

Try to check this condition like

if(!pointOnMinimap())
   continue;
else
   click(pointsArray.get(i);

Comment: I tried with if(!pointOnMinimap()) continue; else click(pointsArray.get(i). Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I did what GhostCat and RealSkeptic said, wrote this part again from scratch and found out that the JButton action listener was the one that caused the loop on the mouse clicks. Thanks you all for helping :D